# How to make Vue js vuetify input allow only 3 digits before decimal and 2 digits after decimal

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to set limit to the total input number to 3. For example, user can input `333`, `123` etc. However, if they use decimal point, they will be allowed to enter 2 digits after decimal point. So, these inputs are valid:

> 123

> 123.33

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
isNumber (event, message) {
  // preventing multiple decimal
  if (!/\d/.test(event.key) && (event.key !== '.' || /\./.test(message))) {
    return event.preventDefault()
  }

  // limiting three numbers before decimal point and two digits after decimal point
  if (/^(\d{0,3}\.)?\d{1,2}$/.test(message)) return event.preventDefault()
 
}
```

But, this regex, `/^(\d{0,3}\.)?\d{1,2}$/` is not working for my case

**[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/lr_73/pen/NWaaWMv?editors=101)**

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using a number input (`<input type="number">`), with a `max` property to control the number of digits, and a small keyup handler to control the value.

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === `num`) {
    if (evt.key === `Backspace`) { return true; }
    const [number, int] = [parseFloat(evt.target.value), parseInt(evt.target.value)];
    evt.target.value = number > evt.target.max 
      ? evt.target.max : number === int 
        ? int : number.toFixed(2);
    document.querySelector(`#value`).textContent = `current value: ${evt.target.value}`;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="num" type="number" step="0.1" max="999.99">
<div id="value"></div>
```

Comment: Actually, I have to use vuetify as that framework has been used in my existing project.

Comment: You can create a number input field in vuetify. See [this Pen](https://codepen.io/kooiinc/pen/jOGGbLL?editors=101)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regex:

```
^\d{0,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

The thing to remember is to make the fractional part, including the `.`, optional.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gz3iux/6)

Comment: This regex is working in the regex101 as my used regex. But, none of these working in my Vuetify project/CodePen demo

Comment: @user1896653 Your regex is not working for all the cases: https://regex101.com/r/Gz3iux/7

Comment: Okay, got it; thanks. But, it need to be worked in the project.